# Do Resharper NotNull attributes work on Extension Methods?

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper, extension-methods, notnull

We are using extension methods to, for instance, return an empty list if the list is null to clean up the code a bit. A simplified example is included below.

The method unfortunately still triggers are warning from Resharper. Using the NotNull attribute works in most cases, but not when using the method as an extension method.

[image: Code Example. Image to include the squiggly lines from resharper.]

I included a screenshot to show the squiggly lines. Notice the blue squiggly line. Notice how the NotNull attribute does what it is supposed to when the method is not called as an extension method, but not when used that way. Obviously we would like to be able to call the method as an extension method.

Is this not possible? Is there some other attribute we can use?

(The green squiggly line is complaining about the fact that we could be calling the method as an extension method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use a [? (null-conditional) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), which doesn't chain - it will shortcircuit the statement if input is null. Thus, if input is null, list will evaluate to null and list.Count will throw a nullreference-exception.

You can wrap the entire thing in parenthesis, like

```
var list = (input?.List).EmptyIfNull();
```

Comment: Thanks. It's so obvious in hindsight. I was just so frustrated from what seemed like a glaring implementatino weakness. Glad it was only me forgetting old tricks.